# Turn a <p> tag into text area

Tags: javascript, html, button

I was trying to make something for my wiki with js that when you click on a text it turns it into textarea with a button and when you click the button it updates the text.

I tried adding button with changing a div value but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`contenteditable` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)

```js
const 
  p_EditOnOff = document.querySelector('p')
, btn_EditOff = document.querySelector('#btn-EditOff')
  ;

p_EditOnOff.addEventListener('click', () =>
  {
  if ( p_EditOnOff.contentEditable === 'true') return;
  p_EditOnOff.contentEditable = true;
  btn_EditOff.classList.toggle('noDisplay',false);
  
  p_EditOnOff.focus();
  })

btn_EditOff.onclick =_=>
  {
  btn_EditOff.classList.toggle('noDisplay',true);
  p_EditOnOff.contentEditable = false;
  }
```

```css
.noDisplay {
  display: none;
}

p[contenteditable="false"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable="false">Some text</p>

<button id="btn-EditOff" class="noDisplay"> end edit </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could hide the paragraph element when it's clicked, and add a textarea and button after it. Then assign an event listener to the button to update the paragraph's `textContent` and display it again.

A basic example:

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Consider putting these two elements in a container
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea'),
    btn = document.createElement('button');
  textarea.value = this.textContent;
  btn.textContent = 'Save';
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    this.textContent = textarea.value;
    this.style.display = '';
    textarea.remove();
    btn.remove();
  });
  this.style.display = 'none';
  this.after(textarea, btn);
});
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
```